# strchr(), How does this correctly find the index of a char

Tags: c, strchr

I'm looking at the example for strchr() on: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/

Why does this correctly find the index? Intuitively it looks like it should be giving a negative index:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "This is a sample string";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Looking for the 's' character in \"%s\"...\n",str);
  pch=strchr(str,'s');
  while (pch!=NULL)
  {
    printf ("found at %d\n",pch-str+1);
    pch=strchr(pch+1,'s');
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Intuitively it looks like it should be giving a negative index:

No, because `strchr` returns a pointer to the place where that character is found. So every time `strchr` returns non-`NULL`, that pointer it will be somewhere "further down" compared to the pointer where it started.

Comment: But would that still be true if you tried it with a pointer to the heap?

Comment: So it would be the address `pch` points to minus the address of `str`?

Comment: @SamDufel Yes, it works with any contiguous piece of 0-terminated memory.

Comment: @asimes The best way to understand how it works is to implement your own `strchr`.

Comment: Another way to understand it is to draw the memory contents on graph paper, labeled with consecutive addresses (start with any positive number). Then emulate by hand what `strchr()` does.

Comment: @SamDufel: Why would it matter if the pointer points into the heap?

Comment: @KeithThompson - Because the memory allocation in the heap tends to run in the opposite direction of the stack (high to low).  Thinking about it some more, it would be pretty complicated if the byte order had to flip back and forth, so I imagine memory is allocated in blocks with the same byte ordering, but decreasing start addresses.

Comment: @SamDufel: Indexing within an array is defined the same way, regardless of how the array is allocated relative to other independently allocated objects.